# Jquery conflict problem

Tags: jquery

Code 1 is conflict with another Jquery function in the code, then I add the **jQuery.noConflict()**(See the Code 2). However, the function didn't work when adding **jQuery.noConflict()**.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

***Code 1***

```
            $(document).ready(function(){          
                $("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                $("#insideTable > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").hide();
                $("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").show();
                $("#insideTable > tbody > tr.odd").click(function(){
                    $(this).next().toggle();
                    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
                });

            });
        </script>
```

***Code 2***

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery.noConflict();         
                    $("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                    $("#insideTable > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").hide();
                    $("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").show();
                    $("#insideTable > tbody > tr.odd").click(function(){
                        $(this).next().toggle();
                        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                    jQuery("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                    jQuery("#insideTable > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").hide();
                    jQuery("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").show();
                    jQuery("#insideTable > tbody > tr.odd").click(function(){
                        jQuery(this).next().toggle();
                        jQuery(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

just replace **$** with **jQuery** and try for this. may working good.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Chandresh. I have tried your solution and it's working. But i do not really understand why replacing $ with jquery. Could you please explain to me? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks.Actually you have used object **$** already in one of the jquery, so if you want to use another jquery in same webpage then you need to change **object**. so we are using **jQuery** as a object for 2nd jquery call.

Answer (score 1):

Try Code 2 like below

```
            var jq = jQuery.noConflict();         
             jq(document).ready(function(){

            jq("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            jq("#insideTable > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            jq("#insideTable > tbody > tr:odd").show();
            jq("#insideTable > tbody > tr.odd").click(function(){
                jq(this).next().toggle();
                jq(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use  jQuery.noConflict() only in case of conflict with another library (taken from documentation):

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

this is not your case and the second script doesn't work because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore

BTW your two snippets of code are the same: are you sure you need both of them?

Comment: Hi Nicola, Thanks for your quick reply. The difference between these snippets is the 2nd snippet have jQuery.noConflict() (see the line 2)